# SQL Server Services empty in SQL Server configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-10

As I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, I noticed that the SQL Server Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager is empty. SQL Server still works perfectly well at the moment. SQL Server 2014 is installed on a local machine.

I have read blogs - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2492/why-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-services/ and 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1469391-1292-1.aspx and still could not resolve the issue.

I backed up databases, uninstalled and re-installed and yet the node is still empty. What should I do?

Updated with screen shot

[image]

SQL Server Configuration Manager Screen

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 just got released.. Are you able to see SQL server services in `services.msc` ? May be after a new update you are able to see it.

Comment: I have turned on Sql Server Distributed Replay Client and Sql Server Distributed Replay Controller. Nothing is visible as of now

Comment: Show the screen shot of Configuration Manager's empty window, too. It's possible you're just looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand, I have updated with screen shot.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what has happened - the type of upgrade you did basically moved all of your applications/services to Windows.old (I bet that's the only place you find sqlservr.exe etc). You'll need to reinstall SQL Server (you should be able to find the mdf/ldf files over there or, better yet, you have backups that you took before the upgrade, right?).

Comment: I did a reinstall after the upgrade As I thought that was the issue or so I was told. And yet I still cannot locate the items under the SQL server service. I need help!  Thank u

Comment: By reinstall, do you mean uninstall and install, or just install a second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the upgrade on my laptop with SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 already installed. The issue I had was that SSCM actually disappeared from the Start Menu, if after repair it would not put them back. I ended up finding them under the Windows root directory, but have since done a complete reinstall of Windows 10 on my laptop, and reinstalled SQL Server.

I would expect you are looking at a similar situation that is going to require a reload of Windows 10. You might try just doing the `refresh`, where it does not completely remove everything...but I doubt that is going to work. I did a factory reset where I went back to Windows 8.1, then forced an upgrade to Windows 10. Which I might add, doing that seemed to have improved Windows 10 at least on my laptop (Lenovo Y 40-80) compared to running it after the upgrade.

One last chance you might attempt is to install the SSMS preview (standalone of SSMS) from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I am considering reinstalling Windows 10 this coming weekend

Comment: @dLight although it was a bit of a pain, it did a much cleaner install for me at least. For reference I utilized this to force Windows 10 to install because you will likely never get the prompt to do it: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

Comment: Thanks. Will go for it this coming weekend and update this post

Comment: I had to reinstall Windows 10 over the weekend and now everything is okay. Thanks Shawn